# Estimating a statistic by combining two different data sources

Tags: time-series, algorithms, estimators

Say you want to estimate a statistic $\theta$ and have two data sources. A sample from data source A can be treated as a low-variance, somewhat biased estimate of $\theta$. A sample from data source B can be treated as a very high-variance, unbiased estimate of $\theta$. The distributions for A and B are otherwise unknown. The bias of A is unknown, but presumed low enough to use A as an initial estimate of $\theta$ until better information becomes available from B.

At each time step, you are presented with a sample from A and a sample from B, and at each time step you want to give your best estimate of $\theta$ based on the data seen so far. $\theta$ is not time-varying, and the samples from A are i.i.d., as are the samples from B. What is a good algorithm for this?

I'd imagine a good solution should be some time-varying weighted average of the mean of the A samples and the mean of the B samples. The weights should favor the low-variance A samples for the initial estimates, and as more samples accumulate, the weights should gradually switch over to the unbiased B samples. But how can we set the schedule for the weights? We need to balance the error resulting from the bias of A against the error resulting from the high variance of the sample mean from B, the second of which will decrease over time as sample size increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two observations at time $t$ are $(y_{1t}, y_{2t})$ you can imagine that they are generated as:
$$\pmatrix{y_{1t} \\ y_{2t}} = \pmatrix{k \\ 1}\theta_t + \pmatrix{\epsilon_{1t} \\ \epsilon_{2t}};$$
$y_{2t}$ is the unbiased observation, $k$ is meant to account for the bias of $y_{1t}$ and can be known or unknown. For instance, if you know that the bias around 10%  the true value and positive, $k=1.10$, otherwise it can be estimated.

For $\theta_t$  you might write:
$$\theta_t = \theta_{t-1} + \eta_t$$
which with the previous equation forms a simple state-space model that you can estimate using a Kalman filter.

Comment: The bias is assumed not too large, but is unknown. It can only be estimated by comparing the long run sample mean of A with the long run sample mean of B. And if you have enough observations from B to do this accurately, then you already have an accurate estimate of $\theta$ from B alone, and no longer need A. So estimating the bias of A is really most of the problem.

Comment: I should also clarify that $\theta$ is not time-varying.

Comment: @clarivate, you do not need a beforehand estimation of the bias, you can just estimate $k$ with the other parameters. Time-invariance of $\theta$ can be accommodated setting the variance of $\theta_t$ to zero.

Comment: What if I just did a t-test for difference of means between the A samples and the B samples? If there is no significant difference then my estimate could be the mean of just the A samples, and if there is a significant difference then my estimate could be the mean of just the B samples. I could also use the test statistic to gradually interpolate between the two cases.

Comment: @causative, a ordinary t-test requires common variance in the two populations. I cannot follow the logic: if there were no significant difference, you would probably want to pool all observations for an unbiased estimator, not just use A.

Comment: You can still use a t-test when the variances are different, see http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/meancomp.htm "Tests of Significance for Two Unknown Means and Unknown Standard Deviations."  The logic of only using A when there's no significant difference is that the variance of B is very high compared to the variance of A, so if we pooled A with B before gathering enough observations, the variance of the overall estimate would be higher than if we just used A.

Comment: @causative, yes, you can use a t-test if you do the right correction, thats why I wrote "rodinary t-test". What you say about the variances assumes you pool A and B observations with equal weights, something which you would never want to do.

Comment: Can you point me to something about appropriately weighting the observations in the case when there is no significant difference in means?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ both have mean $\theta$, that you want to estimate, an unbiased estimator is of the form $\hat\theta = cX+(1-c)Y$, and has variance $c^2\sigma_X^2 + (1-c)^2\sigma_Y^2$. If you minimize this wrt $c$ you arrive to the quite intuitive result that the weights of the observations should be inversely proportional to their variances. This generalize to more than two observations. For a suitable $c$ you whill have a variance which is less than that obtainable from $X$ or $Y$ alone.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.